# Using Python + lxml (xpath) to scrape/extract text from a website and print it

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am a new python learner; almost 3 weeks old.

I am trying to automate some daily tasks by using python. In here, I was trying to scrape a website which is "https://www.germaneveryday.com/", It does generate a new German word every day along with a sentence example. So my plan was to automate this instead of visiting the site everyday.

I followed an online tutorial from here : http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/

And this is the code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.germaneveryday.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

Word = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/h1/a')


print (Word)
```

I did inspect the daily word on the website, and using right click, copy xpath to extract the "tree.xpath" address for the specific html data I am willing to get out and print in my simple code using lxml + python.

Except that every time the output is either an empty parenthesis such as : 
[] or it is some html block that is meaningless As shown here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAjB6.png

My question is that, what is wrong here is it the xpath address or maybe the website has some kind of a layer over the html ?

(Excuse my ignorance using some descriptions such as : layer or address of xpath )

My System Info:

- Windows 7 (x86)
- Python Version is (v3.6.5)
- Web Browser is Chrome 66.0.3359.181

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list index to access the required element and `.text` to print its text.

**Ex:**

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.germaneveryday.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
Word = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/h1/a')[0].text
print (Word)
```

**Output:**

```
heimlich
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It should work

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.germaneveryday.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

word = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/h1/a/text()')


print (word)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as said above by: Rakesh, Davide Fiocco and Devratna

"Use list index to access the required element and .text to print its text"

using the code

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.germaneveryday.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
Word = tree.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/h1/a')[0].text
print (Word)
```

It is working now !