# Find XPath of next sibling python

Tags: python, htmlsession

Here's the outhtml of an element on a webpage

```html
<td valign="top">
                            <script type="text/javascript">sjcap();</script><p><input type="text" id="uword" name="uword" class="" size="20"></p><p><img src="/wps/PA_1_ATAGT15208O2F02M34340U0000/./cimg/31.jpg" width="290" height="80" alt=""></p>
                            </td>
```

I am trying to build xpath for the image and extract the src attribute using HTMLSession `requests_html`
Here's my xpath but this didn't match the element `//input[@id='uword']/following-sibling::p`
I inspected the element and try to use Ctrl + F to find the xpath but I got 0 results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html in your question is not well formed xml (the `<input>` and `<img>` elements aren't closed). Second, the `<p>` element containing the `<img>` child is not a sibling of the `<input>` tag, but of that tag's `<p>` parent. Assuming the html is fixed like this:

```
<td valign="top">
  <script type="text/javascript">sjcap();</script>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="uword" name="uword" class="" size="20"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="/wps/PA_1_ATAGT15208O2F02M34340U0000/./cimg/31.jpg" width="290" height="80" alt=""/>
  </p>
</td>
```

The following xpath

```
//p[./input[@id="uword"]]/following-sibling::p/img/@src
```

or

```
//p/input[@id="uword"]/../following-sibling::p/img/@src
```

should output

```
/wps/PA_1_ATAGT15208O2F02M34340U0000/./cimg/31.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you add an example of a python code of how to print the output?

Comment: @YasserKhalil That is a function of the parser you're using; per SO policy, you should probably post it as a separate question.

Comment: So you suggest using BeautifulSoup?!

Comment: It would depend on the nature and complexity of the original HTML you're parsing. I personally prefer lxml to BeautifulSoup, but it's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried these lines but no success `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = soup.select('//p[./input[@id="uword"]]/following-sibling::p/img/@src')`

Comment: @YasserKhalil If you're going to use xpath, then you HAVE to use lxml; if you're using css selectors (like you're trying in your comment) you can use either - but your comment uses xpath, not css selectors....

Comment: How can I use Xpath in that case? or what's the equivalent css selector?

Comment: Solved by this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657708/using-python-lxml-xpath-to-scrape-extract-text-from-a-website-and-print-it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking to copy the full xpath? It’s different from just copying the xpath. It would be in the /html format if that’s what you want. Right click the element and copy full xpath instead

Comment: Thanks a lot but I would like to build the XPath by myself.

Comment: Oh sorry I think I misunderstood your question. When you say you used Ctrl+F to find the XPath, what did you type in?  And the Xpath you provided was built by you correct? So what are you trying to match it up against?

Comment: I would like to match `<img src="/wps/PA_1_ATAG` element which is a sibling of `//input[@id='uword']`